# The extension called Autodesk.Viewing.Collaboration is not working correctly in Forge Viewer?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I normally quoted Autodesk.Viewing.Collaboration in the js file, and I can see the sharing button in the toolbar, but when I clicked to start viewing, the following error message appeared on the page:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://rtc.api.autodesk.com/socket.io/?sessionID=https://developer.api.autodesk.com/derivativeservice/v2/derivatives/urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:***/output/&EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1605086974047-0' from origin 'http://example.com:10080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."
```

When I used this function before, it was normal. I can't understand the current situation. Can someone help me answer my doubts? How can I handle this situation instead?
And after the sharing behavior is issued, if can I actively control the cancellation of sharing?

Comment: I'm able to reproduce the same issue. I'm afraid it's not related to CORS but rather to the fact that requests to https://rtc.api.autodesk.com fail with `502 Bad Gateway`. The service might be down. We will contact the engineering team and post an official update here.

Comment: Got it,.Thanks for your response.

Comment: Another question, if can I actively control the cancellation of sharing?

Comment: The UI panel for the collaboration feature (`DockingCollabPanel`) includes methods like `startSession` and `endSession` that could perhaps be used to control the session programmatically.

Comment: Btw the collaboration service should now be back online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that this was not a CORS issue. The collaboration service host (https://rtc.api.autodesk.com) was temporarily down, and is now back online.